# Why is there only one line as result for my js code?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code,the output confused me.

```
var count = 0;
function cc(card) {
  switch (card){
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count ++;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      break;
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count --;
      break;
  }
  if (count >0){
    return count+" "+"Bet";
  }
  else{
    return count+" "+"Hold";
  }
}
cc(2);cc(3);
```

It result in `"2 Bet"`,why the output is not
`"1 Bet"`
`"2 Bet"`
In my opinion, `cc(2);`result in `"1 Bet"` ,and `cc(3);` following `cc(2);` result in another `"2 Bet"`,so the result is obvious that two lines in the output
`"1 Bet"`
`"2 Bet"`

Why is there only one line as result for the js code?
`"2 Bet"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just not printing the result. You're just seeing the output of the last function because you're probably running this in the browser console.

If you log each result, you can see that the code does what you expect.

```js
var count = 0;

function cc(card) {
  switch (card) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
      count++;
      break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
      break;
    case 10:
    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
    case 'A':
      count--;
      break;
  }
  if (count > 0) {
    return count + " " + "Bet";
  } else {
    return count + " " + "Hold";
  }
}
console.log(cc(2)); // 1 Bet
console.log(cc(3)); // 2 Bet
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the result of your program is being displayed, and it is the result of the last call you executed, which is `cc(3)`, and results in: "2 Bet".

You are not printing or outputting the result of calling `cc(2)` in anyway.